# ViewPager2 not destroying fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment, android-viewpager2

I have a `DialogFragment` with a `ViewPager2`:

```
public class LightboxFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private ViewPager2 viewPager;

    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;

    public static LightboxFragment newInstance() {
        LightboxFragment fragment = new LightboxFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lightbox, container, false);

        viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        FrameLayout closeButtonContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.close_button_container);
        closeButtonContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getActivity());
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

        public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
            super(fa);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            LightboxVideoFragment fragment = new LightboxVideoFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

    }

}
```

And my `LightboxVideoFragment` looks something like this:

```
public class LightboxVideoFragment extends Fragment {

    private SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;

    private PlayerView playerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.slideshow_video, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(media.getUrls().getMp4());
        exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getContext()).build();
        exoPlayer.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
        playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        exoPlayer.prepare();
        exoPlayer.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            exoPlayer.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            exoPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            exoPlayer.release();
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is this: When the `DialogFragment` is dismissed, the audio from the fragment's video is still playing. Why is this? I've tried adding `onDestroy` in my fragment and setting breakpoints there, but the breakpoint is never called when the dialog is dismissed, nor is `onPause` or `onDetach`.

Does this also mean that the `ExoPlayer` instance is also still alive when the dialog is dismissed?

How can I stop the video's audio when the dialog is dismissed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use viewpager2 inside another Fragment but based on the documentation and the source code of viewpager2 I think you are creating the adapter incorrectly when doing it from a Fragment.

In the `class LightboxFragment` try changing line

`myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getActivity());`

to

`myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(this);`

This is because based on the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter#FragmentStateAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)

> Fragment: if the ViewPager2 lives directly in a Fragment subclass.

You are using it as if the Viewpager2 is living directly in the host activity.

This means you are putting `LightboxVideoFragment` in the same FragmentManager as `LightboxFragment` and the Lifecycle changes to `LightboxFragment` don't affect what are basically siblings to it (not children as they should be)

If you look at the source code of viewpager2 for the constructors as well

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/viewpager2/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter.java#102

The correct constructor ties the Fragments in the viewpager2 adaptor to a host Fragment via `getChildFragmentManager()` and the Fragment's lifecycle and not to the `Activity's` lifecycle.

(I've not experimented or tested this just knowledge from the docs and reading the source code).

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!